# How to save more images in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, image-uploading

In mvc3 application, Product has properties as ImagePath1, ImagePath2, ImagePath3, ImagePath4 and ImagePath5 in string type.
I can save 1 image in this rule.
For 1 image, in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Create( Product product, HttpPostedFileBase file )
{
       var filename = Path.GetFileName( file.FileName );
       var path = Path.Combine( Server.MapPath( "~/UploadFolder/Products" ), filename );
       file.SaveAs( path );
       product.ImagePath1 = filename;
       db.Products.AddObject( product );
       db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I have file upload sample as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function HandleFileButtonClick() {
        document.frmUpload.myFile.click();
        document.frmUpload.txtFakeText.value = document.frmUpload.myFile.value;
    }
</script>
<form name="frmUpload">
<input type="file" name="myFile" style="display: none;">
<input type="text" name="txtFakeText" readonly="true">
<input type="button" onclick="HandleFileButtonClick();" value="Select" class="UploadButton">
</form>
```

but I can not apply thit in Product's create view.

```
@using ( Html.BeginForm( "Create", "Product", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" } ) )
{    
     @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.Name, new { @class = "createInputStyle" } )
     ...                        
     ...// Images here...
     ...
     <input type="submit" value="Create" class="" />
}
```

File upload sample works outside, but when I place upload form into Create form, have problem.
How to save more images?  Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stick the following inside your Html.BeginForm() {}

```
<input type='file' name='ImagePath1' /> 
<input type='file' name='ImagePath2' /> 
<input type='file' name='ImagePath3' /> 
<input type='file' name='ImagePath4' /> 
<input type='file' name='ImagePath5' />
```

Then, on your controller, check `Request.Files`, which should hold these images (providing images were uploaded)

Comment: I wrote so, but I could not change file button's values as "Choose file", "No file chosen". That is why I want use that sample in question.

Comment: update your question to include how you were attempting to capture the multiple files